# Ansible in windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows, ansible

I have a problem with the implementation of script.sh as me failing to recognize the "ansible-playbook" command.

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 25: ansible-playbook: command not found
```

P.D: Here is the link about script.sh

[Is it possible to execute the Vagrant Ansible provisioner on a Windows host machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/541072/is-it-possible-to-execute-the-vagrant-ansible-provisioner-on-a-windows-host-mach/568001#568001)

Comment: What OS is the guest/VM?

Comment: the guest is ubuntu "precise" 64 bits

Comment: How did you install ansible? from pip inside a virtualenv, pip outside a virtualenv, native OS packages?

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but for posterity... I suspect you need to update your PATH to include the directory in which your ansible and ansible-playbook executables are located.  Check if they're in your path on *nix:

```
which ansible-playbook
```

If not, fix that first, or try using the full path to the executable in the script.

This may be of interest, http://www.ansible.com/blog/windows-is-coming